# integration F(x)

Tags: integration

$$F(x)=\int\limits_{\ln2}^{x}\tanh(t) \mathrm{d}t$$

would this become $$F(x)=\tanh(t) \mathrm{d}t$$
or i have to integrate it 
$$F(x)=\int \tanh(t) \mathrm{d}t$$
$$F(x)=\int \frac{e^{t}-e^{-t}}{e^{t}+e^{-t}} \mathrm{d}t$$
$$F(x)= \ln(e^{t}+e^{-t})$$ and sub $x$ and $\ln 2$ to find the solution?

Comment: Yes. $ {}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It is faster to use Wolfram Alpha to check your solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1):

So the last expression can be expressed as $$F(x)=ln(e^t+e^{-t})|_{ln(2)}^x,$$ from there you just plug in the top bound $x$, and subtract it by plugging in the lower boun $ln(2)$.